# AngularJS and Html select using object array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have the following data items, that i would like to bind to a html select element and show the available answers

```
var array = [{ name: 'bob', isSelected: false}, {name: 'james', isSelected: false}];
```

The isSelected property on each item will either be true or false.  If true, i want that item to be selected in the select element.

I also need the isSelected property to be updated to true/false depending on whether that item is selected or not.

I have tried using this, but nothing displays

```
<select ng-options="a.name for a in array">
</select>
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: If it is not a `select multiple` why do you need a `isSelected` property? The value of the `select` would be whatever name is selected.

Comment: Please only ask questions that have not been answered before on stack.

Comment: Also you need an `ng-model` attribute for the value to be stored in for `ng-options` to work. I suggest you do it similar to http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3629/

Comment: Everyone is right about you needing ng-model to do the actual binding once you select something, but the main reason nothing is showing up in the select is because you have var array instead of $scope.array.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a binding in your example. Here is a fuller example from the AngularJS documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select. In other words, ng-model="" is required.

Answer (score 1):

Instead storing each item's isSelected property, you should use the ng-model to retrieve the value of the `<select>`

for example:

```
<select ng-model="result" ng-options="a.name for a in array" multiple>
</select>
```

You selection will bind result. in this case. if you select first option. result will be [{name: 'bob'}].

Note that a multiple select's result is always an array